# Using environment variables in fontspec path

Tags: xetex, fontspec, windows, environment-variables

Fontspec font inclusions can be lengthy, so I wanted to create a template that has the fonty stuff already done. I have a working template, but it uses an absolute path `Path = C:/Users/Bolpat/Documents/FontName` setting in fontspec's font inclusion mechanism. (I include the fonts by file, not installed ones.) The user profile name is in that absolute path, which I couldn't avoid, since the template should Just Work™ without change wherever the derived document is located. It works perfectly on my machine and my profile. I'd like to have a way to make it more flexible so I could use the template on different machines or even share it with others.
I thought about environment variables like `USERPROFILE` and found [this](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/An_introduction_to_Kpathsea_and_how_TeX_engines_search_for_files), but when testing it, it didn't work, i.e. setting `Path = $USERPROFILE/Documents/FontName` didn't do the job. While it may work on other OSes, `~/Documents/FontName` doesn't work on Windows.

I think I could expect peers to have the font files in a specific folder; but mainly, this is for myself.

Comment: If you use kpathsea, `~/Documents/FontName` should work (the documntation states that on Windows, `~` gets replaced by the `USERPROFILE` environment variable), but you have to suppress the special handling of `~` e.g. using `\string~`. In this case, you would need `\string~/Documents/...`. Things might be different if you use MikTeX which has it's own lookup library.

Comment: I'm currently using MikTeX, but gave it a shot anyway. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: In MikTeX, you might be able [to set `TEXINPUTS` to your directory.](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/envvars.html)

Comment: why don't you install the fonts in a better place? Either in your system font folder, or in a local texmf-tree in e.g. fonts/opentype? Then xetex could find them without any absolute (or other) pathes.